# How to use !important keyword in a mixin?

Tags: sass

I can't get Sass to output the `!important` keyword with a mixin, I've tried:

```
@include font-size($font-size-sml) !important;
```

And:

```
@include font-size($font-size-sml !important);
```

It always throws an error.

**EDIT**

I ended up with this which works fine:

```
@mixin font-size($font-size, $sledge-hammer: "") {
    font-size: $font-size #{$sledge-hammer};
    font-size: ($font-size / $base-font-size)+rem #{$sledge-hammer};
    line-height: ceil($font-size / $base-line-height) * ($base-line-height / $font-size);
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: We need to see the mixin you're calling, the problem lies there.

Comment: Here's the mixin:
`@mixin font-size($font-size) {
    font-size: $font-size;
    font-size: ($font-size / $base-font-size)*1rem;
    line-height: ceil($font-size / $base-line-height) * ($base-line-height / $font-size);
}`

Comment: @ChrisPearce if provided answer solved your issue please accept it

Answer (score 9):

You can't add `!important` to whole mixin in SASS (It is possible in LESS I think) like you're trying to do in first example.

Second example works for me (you can pass !important with a parameter), I mean, if you use `$font-size-sml` directly as a property value it works, so maybe check your syntax.

But if it's really not working for you, you can do something with flag, set a important_flag as a mixin parameter and then use if-else statement in mixin. Something like this:

```
@mixin large-text($prop, $is_imp: false) {
    @if $is_imp == false {
        font-size: $prop;
    } @else {
        font-size: $prop !important;
    }
}
```

Maybe it's not a glamorous way to do it, but it works ;-)

Comment: I can't get the 2nd example working, I've just started writing Sass so I'm new to the syntax. I'd rather not use a mixin to apply `!important` as it seems overkill, I thought it would be fairly easy to be able to add it when calling a mixin?

Comment: in your code, you use `$font-size` to do simple math, like `$font-size / $base-font-size`. So you can pass as parameter `$font-size-sml !important` because it will look like `$font-size-sml !important / $base-font-size` which is wrong

Comment: Not having much luck with it I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `if(condition, when-true, when-false)` function.

So the code will be simplest and compact:

```scss
@mixin large-text($size, $isImportant: false) {
    font-size: $size if($isImportant, !important, null);
}
```